# Show products based on my custom attributes to second addon domain site

Tags: php, joomla-api

I'm using virtuemart 2.0 and joomla 2.5 with a commercial template mowebso_ecommerce - Default.

I want to show some products on my first website eg. firstsite.com and some products on second site eg. secondsite.com. But the problem is that i don't want to install joomla and virtuemart on second site. It will use everything from first site and it will show different theme. The role of secondsite.com will be only to show some products that cannot be shown to firstsite.com due to some reason(prescribed medicines) .

When user searches a product from firstsite.com (which i don't want to display in fisrtsite.com but want to show on secondsite.com) then i want him to redirect to secondsite.com and display a different theme rather than showing the same theme of firstsite.com so that for a user it will be just like a different site from firstsite.com. I also want to use same database for login and everything purpose and same session so that user login only on one site and can purchase from both sites. Everything will be managable from firstsite.com and secondsite.com will be for display purpose for some products.

I have purchase secondsite.com domain but not any hosting plan for it. It will use firstsite.com hosting instead. Maybe addon domain will work for me in this case.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since I used VirtueMart and I can't be overly specific but I think there may be a way to do this with a somewhat different approach.  It seems to me that there is a plugin or component that will allow you to set up a multi-vendor VirtueMart mall.  In effect a "virtual" shopping center.  Then it should be possible to transfer from a "catalog" to the correct store to complete a purchase.  It would use the same database and you should be able to give each virtual store its own theme and brand.  There is only 1 install of Joomla and VirtueMart required.

I'm sorry I can't be more specific but I just don't have time to research this right now.  Nonetheless, I hope this gives you a fresh approach to your requirements.  Keep us posted of your progress.

Comment: It seems great. I'll explore more on `multi-vendor VirtueMart Mall` to work for my situation. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect that this will be possible without a huge amount of hacking/customization, if at all.  Most especially because the products, cart/ecommerce, and the User and Account information all have to be available to the site with VM installed, and keeping sessions between the two sites in synch with the cart & user seems like a hurdle that would kill the idea for me.

I can only imagine a custom component for Site2 that would pull product info from Site1, then have the ability to add it to the cart on Site1

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that this will be very difficult to alter all those virtuemart files to accomplish this task, but is this possible to add a custom fields eg. isprescribed and add its value to 1 , when its 1 then don't show it on first site but show on second site.